# Заменить в строке S последнее вхождение строки S1 на строку S2

Tags: c++

можно ли в этой задаче не использовать метод find() ?

Comment: Можно, Страуструп разрешил.

Comment: каждую задачу можно решать многими способами.

Comment: Можете воспользоваться регулярными выражениями, можете сами написать поиск по строке (если будите, то прочитайте п про з-функцию и постфикс-функцию

Comment: @koshachok префикс-функция а не постфикс =)

Comment: @АндрейМоскаленко ага, точно :)